# Multilevel logistic regression in R: ML vs. Bayesian estimation

Tags: logistic, maximum-likelihood, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

I hope you can help me with an issue I encountered while trying to build a multilevel logistic regression model in R. I get different results depending on whether I fit the model using Maximum Likelihood estimation or Bayesian inference.

The basic situation is the following. A 2x2 contingency table tells me that people in Northern California are more likely to have Trait A (traitA) than people in Southern California. The table shows frequencies and percentages in parentheses.

[image: contingency table]

To start off, I replicated this finding with a simple logistic regression in R with south_ca as a binary predictor:

```
fit1 <- glm(traitA~ 1 + south_ca, data=dat, family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(fit1)
```

The result:

```
Call:
glm(formula = traitA ~ 1 + south_ca, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = dat1)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-1.233  -0.979  -0.979   1.123   1.390  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)    0.130      0.170    0.76   0.4456   
south_ca      -0.616      0.213   -2.90   0.0038 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
    Null deviance: 546.07  on 398  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 537.62  on 397  degrees of freedom
  (52 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 541.6
Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

The Bayesian version yields comparable results. The point estimate for south_ca is similar and the 95% confidence interval does not include zero.

```
t_prior <- student_t(df = 7, location = 0, scale = 2.5)
fit1bayes <- stan_glm(traitA ~ 1 + south_ca,
                    data = dat, 
                    family = binomial(link = "logit"),
                    prior = t_prior, prior_intercept = t_prior,
                    QR = FALSE,
                    iter = 2000,
                    adapt_delta = 0.96)
summary(fit1bayes)
```

The result:

```
Model Info:

 function:  stan_glm
 family:    binomial [logit]
 formula:   traitA ~ 1 + south_ca
 algorithm: sampling
 priors:    see help('prior_summary')
 sample:    4000 (posterior sample size)
 num obs:   399

Estimates:
                mean   sd     2.5%   25%    50%    75%    97.5%
(Intercept)      0.1    0.2   -0.2    0.0    0.1    0.2    0.5 
south_ca        -0.6    0.2   -1.0   -0.7   -0.6   -0.5   -0.2 
mean_PPD         0.4    0.0    0.4    0.4    0.4    0.5    0.5 
log-posterior -272.6    1.0 -275.4 -273.0 -272.3 -271.9 -271.7 

Diagnostics:
              mcse Rhat n_eff
(Intercept)   0.0  1.0  2658 
south_ca      0.0  1.0  2641 
mean_PPD      0.0  1.0  3477 
log-posterior 0.0  1.0  1590
```

Now, it happens to be the case that people were assessed at 3 sites in Northern CA and at 2 sites in Southern CA, and I want to take between-sites variation into account in my model.

ML estimation:

```
M0.1 <- glmer(traitA ~ south_ca + (1|site), data = dat, family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 30)
summary(M0.1)
```

The result:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Adaptive Gauss-Hermite Quadrature, nAGQ = 30) [glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: traitA ~ south_ca + (1 | site)
   Data: dat
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa")

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   542.3    554.2   -268.1    536.3      396 

Scaled residuals: 
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-1.136 -0.860 -0.725  0.969  1.380 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 site   (Intercept) 0.0402   0.201   
Number of obs: 399, groups:  site, 5

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)    0.131      0.206    0.64    0.526  
south_ca      -0.606      0.282   -2.15    0.031 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The difference between Northern CA and Southern CA continues to be significant.

Now the Bayesian approach:

```
t_prior <- student_t(df = 7, location = 0, scale = 2.5)
M0.1bayes <- stan_glmer(traitA ~ south_ca + (1|site),
                    data = dat, 
                    family = binomial(link = "logit"),
                    prior = t_prior, prior_intercept = t_prior,
                    QR = FALSE,
                    iter = 2000,
                    adapt_delta = 0.96)
summary(M0.1bayes, digits = 2)
```

The result:

```
Model Info:

 function:  stan_glmer
 family:    binomial [logit]
 formula:   traitA ~ south_ca + (1 | site)
 algorithm: sampling
 priors:    see help('prior_summary')
 sample:    4000 (posterior sample size)
 num obs:   399
 groups:    site (5)

Estimates:
                            mean    sd      2.5%    25%     50%     75%     97.5%
(Intercept)                  0.12    0.35   -0.61   -0.07    0.12    0.31    0.79
south_ca                    -0.56    0.50   -1.57   -0.85   -0.58   -0.30    0.52
b[(Intercept) sit           -0.09    0.36   -0.85   -0.27   -0.06    0.10    0.59
b[(Intercept) site:2]       -0.12    0.36   -0.89   -0.29   -0.08    0.07    0.57
b[(Intercept) site:3]        0.24    0.38   -0.43    0.02    0.19    0.43    1.09
b[(Intercept) site:4]       -0.26    0.40   -1.20   -0.44   -0.20   -0.03    0.42
b[(Intercept) site:5         0.20    0.39   -0.65    0.01    0.18    0.40    1.00
Sigma[site:(Intercept)       0.31    0.63    0.00    0.05    0.14    0.34    1.68
mean_PPD                     0.43    0.03    0.37    0.41    0.43    0.46    0.50
log-posterior             -279.74    2.53 -285.58 -281.18 -279.42 -277.87 -275.84

Diagnostics:
                                    mcse Rhat n_eff
(Intercept)                         0.01 1.00 1819 
south_ca                            0.01 1.00 1155 
b[(Intercept) site:1]               0.01 1.00 1935 
b[(Intercept) site:2]               0.01 1.00 1988 
b[(Intercept) site:3]               0.01 1.00 1903 
b[(Intercept) site:4]               0.01 1.00  975 
b[(Intercept) site:5]               0.01 1.00 1091 
Sigma[site:(Intercept),(Intercept)] 0.02 1.00 1028 
mean_PPD                            0.00 1.00 4000 
log-posterior                       0.08 1.00 1091
```

As you can see, the point estimates for south_ca are similar (ML: -0.61, Bayesian: -0.56), but with Bayesian estimation, the 95% confidence interval includes zero. Thus, I get a significant effect for south_ca with ML estimation, but not with Bayesian estimation.

What kind of conclusions can I draw from these findings about the prevalence of Trait A in Northern and Southern CA? Should I prefer the Bayesian estimates over the ML estimates? The Bayesian analysis seems to suggest that there was little variation in Trait A between sites and, consequently, no regional (North-South) difference, but that conclusion seems to be add odds with the raw data in the contingency table.

Comment: I am not familiar with R. Could you tell me what prior is used for variance of random intercept in your second Bayesian approach?

Comment: And the prior for the between site SD or variance? I suspect that might be crucial here given how few sites there are.

Comment: I'm using a Student t prior with 7 degrees of freedom and a scale of 2.5, following [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstanarm/vignettes/binomial.html) recommendation for estimating GLMs for binary/binomial data with [RStanArm](http://mc-stan.org/interfaces/rstanarm) (the R package that provides easy access to Stan.

Comment: I mean the prior for this parameter: Your estimate is here:        Sigma[site:(Intercept)       0.31  . Your data just provide 5 intercepts, so the information for estimating this parameter is so weak such that the final estimate may be dominated by prior. I think R uses the default prior for you, but I do not know how to find it.

Comment: I did specify a student distribution with 7 df, a mean of 0, and a scale of 2.5 as the prior for all parameters, but then RStanArm likely does some internal rescaling and I also run the model with the option to do internal reparameterization. _However_, there is a function that produces a plot of medians and central intervals comparing parameter draws from the prior and posterior distributions. Based on this plot, the prior median for Sigma[site] is about 0.45.

Comment: I just noticed that in chapter 19.6 of their 2007 book, Gelman and Hill discuss the choice of prior distribution for group-level variance parameters in multilevel models. They note that "some purportedly noninformative prior distributions can unduly affect inferences, especially
for problems where the number of groups J is small or the group-level 
deviation is close to zero," which certainly seems to be the case in my example.